# Loop through JSON in dataLayer

Tags: javascript, loops, google-datalayer

I would like to get the summed value of all the arrays in the "products" object (price * quantity). The summed value should be returned in the return.

Do you have any ideas how to do that?

```
{
   "event": "checkout",
   "ecommerce": {
      "checkout": {
         "actionField": {
            "step": 2,
            "option": "Initiate checkout",
            "action": "checkout"
         },
         "products": [
            {
               "id": "52",
               "name": "Turystyczna kuchenka gazowa  SMILE-KN-03/1K",
               "price": 161.788618,
               "brand": "",
               "category": "kuchenki-elektryczne-i-gazowe",
               "variant": "",
               "quantity": "1"
            },
            {
               "id": "36",
               "name": "Kuchnia gazowa  MPM-51-KGF-21",
               "price": 641.463415,
               "brand": "",
               "category": "kuchnie-gazowe",
               "variant": "",
               "quantity": "1"
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "gtm.uniqueEventId": 12
}
```

Comment: Please replace the picture of code with a text-based [mcve]

Comment: What have you attempted so far and what issues have you had?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const g = {
  event: 'checkout',
  ecommerce: {
    checkout: {
      actionField: {
        step: 2,
        option: 'Initiate checkout',
        action: 'checkout',
      },
      products: [
        {
          id: '52',
          name: 'Turystyczna kuchenka gazowa  SMILE-KN-03/1K',
          price: 161.788618,
          brand: '',
          category: 'kuchenki-elektryczne-i-gazowe',
          variant: '',
          quantity: '1',
        },
        {
          id: '36',
          name: 'Kuchnia gazowa  MPM-51-KGF-21',
          price: 641.463415,
          brand: '',
          category: 'kuchnie-gazowe',
          variant: '',
          quantity: '1',
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  'gtm.uniqueEventId': 12,
};
const c = g.ecommerce.checkout.products.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc += curr.price * curr.quantity;
  return acc;
}, 0);

console.log(c)
```

guess you want something like this?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).